# PHP Regex look ahead and look behind - both must not match?

Tags: php, regex

I am currently looking for a way to remove fullstops from a string in certain places.

I want it so that it will remove fullstops only if 2 conditions are not met;

There is not a digit before the fullstop.

**AND**

There is not a digit after the fullstop.

I currently have this regex

```
'#(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)#'
```

But this does not remove fullstops in strings such as

```
'hello.1', '1.hello'
```

I am guessing that as there is either a digit before or after the fullstop the match fails and it is not recognized.

How can I make it so that both the look ahead and look behind must be met in order for there to be a match and the fullstop get removed correctly?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I want it to remove fullstops when and only when there is not a digit before **~OR~** there is not a digit after the fullstop. So there can only be a fullstop if the string is like so `(a digit).(a digit)` but will remove fullstops in any other circumstances.

Comment: Your question seems contradictory to me. `There is not a digit before the fullstop` AND `There is not a digit after the fullstop`, if you're using `and` it will only match when both conditions are met, for which your example strings correctly fail to match. Did you mean `or`?

Comment: I mean I want it to remove fullstops when and only when there is not a digit before AND there is not a digit after the fullstop. So there can only be a fullstop if it is like so `1122.2323`

Comment: Your phrasing in the question is confusing. Can you give example of expected output of "1.6" and "h.j"?

Comment: I edited the question sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You did it again. :-p `not (before AND after)` is not the same as `not before AND not after`. According to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), it's the same as `not before OR not after`.

Comment: Yes the phrasing is still incorrect, you can rephrase it in 2 days: Keep the dot when there's a digit before AND after; Remove the dot when there's a non-digit before OR after.

Comment: Lol I am confused :S I will have to read up on De Morgans Laws which I never even heard of!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
'#((?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d))#'
```

It will remove the dot if it is preceded or succeeded by non-digit.

Comment: I didn't think of this so instead of having 1 big pattern I have to split it, thanks :)